# Android app check play Integrity Unverified invalid requests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I've integrated Firebase App Check into my Flutter app following the documentation provided by Firebase.

I've meticulously followed all the steps outlined in the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider) to integrate Firebase App Check.

However, I'm encountering an issue where Firebase App Check fails with unverified request for build variant, including debug, release builds in real device. Even builds uploaded to the **internal track** on Google Play Console do not resolve the problem.

How can I effectively test Firebase App Check to ensure it functions correctly? Should I upload the build to the closed test track on Google Play Console for accurate testing?